# How to get the path of a directory of a script using sql query?. The SQL query is run by same script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query which is running by script while I am publishing the code in .net,

My problem is that, I need a SQL query to find the directory of same script.

Please help me to do so.

Comment: There is not enough information for anyone to be able to help you. What RDBMS are we talking about? What kind of script are you executing, and how?

Comment: @ninesided I am using MS SQL server as RDBMS. SQL file is running while I am publishing an XML script in the .NetFramework. IS it enough?

Comment: How is the SQL query kicked off?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the SQL Server client cares where the script is being executed from. Your best bet would be to figure out what the path of the script is before you execute it and pass it in as a parameter, or embed it in the script itself.